# "Go to symbol" in Visual Studio disassembly?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, disassembly

I have the Disassembly tab open in Visual Studio. (There is no source code available.)

I can't figure this out:

How do I put a breakpoint at the beginning of the exported function `Foo` in the DLL `Bar.dll`?

Comment: If it were in WinDbg (which probably isn't any worse than the IDE since you don't have the source code anyway), I'd do `bu bar!Foo`.

Comment: @Alex: Hm... is it easy to do something like `(char**)eax + 4` in WinDbg to view e.g. a string, like it is in Visual Studio? If I know how to do it then I might use it...

Comment: If you let Windbg know where the symbol files (.pdb) are, you'll be able to inspect local and global variables as usual (open locals and watch windows, type in global var names in watch window).

Comment: @Alex: But the problem is that I don't have any symbols... `eax` is a register, not a symbol

Comment: take the eax value, say it's equal 0x1234, type in something like `(char**)0x1238` or `*(char**)0x1238` in the watch window.

Comment: @Alex: er, `EAX` obviously changes its value every time. I can't keep on changing it by hand on every iteration...

Comment: Try using the `??` command with a C++ expression involving `@eax`.