# Navigate to function in Visual Studio disassembly

Tags: visual-studio, disassembly, debug-symbols

I am debugging a native program and only have symbols of some of the assemblies. For one of the assemblies I do have symbols (d3dx9_43.dll in this case), I want to set a breakpoint in certain functions. How can you navigate to a function within the disassembly window for Visual Studio or set a function breakpoint using the symbols?

I found this [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/context-operator-cpp?view=vs-2019), but this way of addressing does not seem to work.
I also found other related questions, but they do lack an answer for this use-case. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737798/go-to-symbol-in-visual-studio-disassembly) one has no answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635231/disassembly-visual-studio) only answers how to navigate to a hex address.

Comment: It's been a while, but I think this should still work: In the breakpoints window, click "Add breakpoint" and then enter the name of the function at which you want to break. This inserts a breakpoint at the start of that function.

Comment: I tried that, but it always returns that it cannot find the function.